# Match and merge a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I have a list of 8 dataframes, where each dataframe contains 6 columns and more than 50000 rows:
[image]
I want to match and merge these dataframes by the `gene` column and eliminate other rows, to have in the end the same number of rows and to convert it to a table.

This is my data:
https://github.com/EsToHi/Data-to-merge/tree/main/DATA

This is my code to read files into the list:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

file_path <- fs::dir_ls("DATA")
file_cont <- list()

for (i in seq_along(file_path)) {
  file_cont[[i]] <- read.delim(
    file = file_path[[i]]
  )
}
```

Comment: I suggest makinjg your question reproducible with some *minimal* sample data. That way, people do not have to download your data from github. I'm sure you can whip up some mock-data that illustrates your question, without it having to be 8 files of 50k lines ;-)

Comment: @Wimpel Thanks for the advice, it's just my first time to ask a question I used to found answers without asking.. I'll try to simplify the question

Comment: also, what sould your output look like?

Comment: @Wimpel it must be a dataframe that combine all the eight data.frames with 6 columns reapeted for each dataframe so it must be in the end 6 x 8 = 48 columns, in the rows it is enough to have the common ones between all dataframes.

Comment: Are you sure you want to cbind the tables and not rbind the tables? A quick glance showed all data files have the same column names. Reading your data in requires some thought and can save you lots of trouble later on your analysis.